# mysql performance_schema how to get event time from events_statements_current table

Tags: mysql, sql

I googled a lot for this, and don't see anyone talking about it, so it must be a simple issue, but still it has me stumped.
This performance_schema table - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-statements-current-table.htm has timer_start and TIMER_END columns. Accordintg to the documentation " The TIMER_START and TIMER_END values indicate when event timing started and ended" .
One small problem. It's a bigint and not a date. How do I convert it to a date?

I saw one blogger suggest that it's the number of time units since the server was started. In my case statements are supposed to be measured to a nanosecond (10^9). So if I have a timer_start value of 3723676792253626000 that would mean 3723676792 s which would be unlikely since the server uptime is 3723716 s. a simple comparison of the number of digits in these two numbers would lead me to think that the unit of time is really picoseconds (10^12).
so the question is :
1. is timer_start really the number of units from the last restart?
2. if so, why is it in picoseconds when setup_timers indicates nanoseconds?

TIA

Answer (score 6):

Here is a corrected version for MySQL 5.7:

```sql
SELECT
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM performance_schema.global_status WHERE VARIABLE_NAME='UPTIME') - TIMER_START*10e-13 second) AS `start_time`,
    ROUND(timer_wait*10E-10, 3) AS `wait in (ms)`,
    sql_text,
    current_schema
FROM performance_schema.events_statements_history_long;
```

The fixes are:

- get `global_status` from `performance_schema` (introduced in MySQL 5.7)
- fix `wait in (ms)` (10E-8 vs. 10E-10) + formatting; example test is the following SQL query: `SELECT SLEEP(0.5)`
- the returned columns
- uses the "long" history table (`events_statements_history_long`)

Comment: Great Work!! This query is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

ok, I was able to partially figure it out. Answer to the first question is yes. Here is a query that converts the timer_start value to a time stamp that a human can recognize:

```sql
select  
date_sub(now(),INTERVAL (select VARIABLE_VALUE from information_schema.global_status where variable_name='UPTIME')-TIMER_START*10e-13 second) `start_time`  
,timer_wait/10E-8 `wait in (ms)`  
,timer_wait  
,sql_text  
,digest_text   
from performance_schema.events_statements_history
```