# How to calculate real time of column TIMER_START in table performance_schema.global_status in mysql8?

Tags: mysql

I want to know how to calculate real time of column TIMER_START in table performance_schema.global_status in mysql8,this column is a big number,and can't be understanded by human.

I calculate with this sql:

```
SELECT
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM performance_schema.global_status WHERE VARIABLE_NAME='UPTIME') - TIMER_START*10e-12 second) AS `start_time`,
    ROUND(timer_wait*10E-9, 3) AS `wait in (ms)`,
    sql_text,
    current_schema
FROM performance_schema.events_statements_history_long;
```

but it turns out to be a wrong time.

I read this document:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-timing.html.
What I think is useful is this part(section: Performance Schema Timer Representation in Events):

> The timer baseline (“time zero”) occurs at Performance Schema initialization during server startup. TIMER_START and TIMER_END values in events represent picoseconds since the baseline. TIMER_WAIT values are durations in picoseconds.

Since 1 picosecond = 10^(-12) second,I calculate real_time of column TIMER_START,but it turns out to be a wrong time.

Then I find a similar question:
[mysql performance_schema how to get event time from events_statements_current table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607249/mysql-performance-schema-how-to-get-event-time-from-events-statements-current-ta)

In it's answers,I find this:

```
SELECT
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM performance_schema.global_status WHERE VARIABLE_NAME='UPTIME') - TIMER_START*10e-13 second) AS `start_time`,
    ROUND(timer_wait*10E-10, 3) AS `wait in (ms)`,
    sql_text,
    current_schema
FROM performance_schema.events_statements_history_long;
```

Use this sql,I get correct time.Comparing with my way,the difference is:it use `TIMER_START*10e-13 second`,and I use `TIMER_START*10e-12 second`.

Because I'm a beginner and don't  have 50 reputation to comment.I can't comment that answer,so I have to ask a new question.

What confuses me is that since

> TIMER_START and TIMER_END values in events represent picoseconds

as I find in mysql document before.

Why can I get correct time using `TIMER_START*10e-13 second` instead of
`TIMER_START*10e-12 second` which is one picosecond.

By the way,I can't understand `timer_wait*10E-10`,since 1 second = 10^(3) ms and then 1 picosecond = 10^(-9) ms.To convert picosecond to ms,it should be `timer_wait*10E-9`

And when I google,I find this blog:
[https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/mysql-80-how-to-display-long-transactions](https://stackoverflow.com)
It also use `TIMER_START*10e-13 second`.

My mysql version is 8.0.27.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Mysql is using scientific notation - [Scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

Therefore 10e2 is actually 10*10<sup>2</sup>.

To get the result you want, you would use 1e-9 which is 1*10<sup>-9</sup>

Comment: I confuse notation e and ^. xey means x*(10^y),but x^y means just x^y.Thanks a lot.